# Merging columns in same file using linux

Tags: linux, concatenation, multiple-columns

I'm working in Linux with a large table of the following layout:

```
1 123456
2 234567
3 345678
```

And I would like to merge the columns, producing the following in a new file:

```
1_123456
2_234567
3_345678
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed regular expressions.

```
sed 's/ /_/' file >new_file
```